# Unable to call a function from a custom module

Tags: python, module

I am trying to try my hands on NLP.

Below is my model,

```
from keras import backend as K 
K.clear_session() 
latent_dim = 500 

# Encoder 
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_len_text,)) 
enc_emb = Embedding(x_voc_size, latent_dim,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs) 

#LSTM 1 
encoder_lstm1 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True) 
encoder_output1, state_h1, state_c1 = encoder_lstm1(enc_emb) 

#LSTM 2 
encoder_lstm2 = LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True) 
encoder_output2, state_h2, state_c2 = encoder_lstm2(encoder_output1) 

#LSTM 3 
encoder_lstm3=LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True) 
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c= encoder_lstm3(encoder_output2) 

# Set up the decoder. 
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,)) 
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(y_voc_size, latent_dim,trainable=True) 
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs) 

#LSTM using encoder_states as initial state
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True) 
decoder_outputs,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,initial_state=[state_h, state_c]) 

#Attention Layer
attn_layer = attention(name='AttentionLayer') 
attn_out, attn_states = attention([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs]) 

# Concat attention output and decoder LSTM output 
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attn_out])

#Dense layer
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(y_voc_size, activation='softmax')) 
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input) 

# Define the model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs) 
model.summary()
```

Now, here the "Attention Layer" used a class in a custom module called attention.py.

It is in my local directory with path `F:/attentionLayer/attention`

I have imported this and `from attentionLayer.attention import AttentionLayer`, however on running the module, I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-9ff46e455cf1> in <module>
     29 
     30 #Attention Layer
---> 31 attn_layer = attention(name='AttentionLayer')
     32 attn_out, attn_states = attention([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])
     33 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

For your information, attention.py is below,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K


class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    """
    This class implements Bahdanau attention (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf).
    There are three sets of weights introduced W_a, U_a, and V_a
     """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.

        self.W_a = self.add_weight(name='W_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[0][2], input_shape[0][2])),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        self.U_a = self.add_weight(name='U_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][2], input_shape[0][2])),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        self.V_a = self.add_weight(name='V_a',
                                   shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[0][2], 1)),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)

        super(AttentionLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, inputs, verbose=False):
        """
        inputs: [encoder_output_sequence, decoder_output_sequence]
        """
        assert type(inputs) == list
        encoder_out_seq, decoder_out_seq = inputs
        if verbose:
            print('encoder_out_seq>', encoder_out_seq.shape)
            print('decoder_out_seq>', decoder_out_seq.shape)

        def energy_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing energy for a single decoder state
            inputs: (batchsize * 1 * de_in_dim)
            states: (batchsize * 1 * de_latent_dim)
            """

            assert_msg = "States must be an iterable. Got {} of type {}".format(states, type(states))
            assert isinstance(states, list) or isinstance(states, tuple), assert_msg

            """ Some parameters required for shaping tensors"""
            en_seq_len, en_hidden = encoder_out_seq.shape[1], encoder_out_seq.shape[2]
            de_hidden = inputs.shape[-1]

            """ Computing S.Wa where S=[s0, s1, ..., si]"""
            # <= batch size * en_seq_len * latent_dim
            W_a_dot_s = K.dot(encoder_out_seq, self.W_a)

            """ Computing hj.Ua """
            U_a_dot_h = K.expand_dims(K.dot(inputs, self.U_a), 1)  # <= batch_size, 1, latent_dim
            if verbose:
                print('Ua.h>', U_a_dot_h.shape)

            """ tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua) """
            # <= batch_size*en_seq_len, latent_dim
            Ws_plus_Uh = K.tanh(W_a_dot_s + U_a_dot_h)
            if verbose:
                print('Ws+Uh>', Ws_plus_Uh.shape)

            """ softmax(va.tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua)) """
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.squeeze(K.dot(Ws_plus_Uh, self.V_a), axis=-1)
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.softmax(e_i)

            if verbose:
                print('ei>', e_i.shape)

            return e_i, [e_i]

        def context_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing ci using ei """

            assert_msg = "States must be an iterable. Got {} of type {}".format(states, type(states))
            assert isinstance(states, list) or isinstance(states, tuple), assert_msg

            # <= batch_size, hidden_size
            c_i = K.sum(encoder_out_seq * K.expand_dims(inputs, -1), axis=1)
            if verbose:
                print('ci>', c_i.shape)
            return c_i, [c_i]

        fake_state_c = K.sum(encoder_out_seq, axis=1)
        fake_state_e = K.sum(encoder_out_seq, axis=2)  # <= (batch_size, enc_seq_len, latent_dim

        """ Computing energy outputs """
        # e_outputs => (batch_size, de_seq_len, en_seq_len)
        last_out, e_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            energy_step, decoder_out_seq, [fake_state_e],
        )

        """ Computing context vectors """
        last_out, c_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            context_step, e_outputs, [fake_state_c],
        )

        return c_outputs, e_outputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        """ Outputs produced by the layer """
        return [
            tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][0], input_shape[1][1], input_shape[1][2])),
            tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1][0], input_shape[1][1], input_shape[0][1]))
        ]
```

TIA. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attention` is a module. You probably want to write:

```py
#Attention Layer
attn_layer = attention.AttentionLayer(name='AttentionLayer') 
attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer.call([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])
```

Comment: I did what you said, I got the following error: ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-cc03364561fc> in <module>
     30 #Attention Layer
     31 attn_layer = attention.AttentionLayer(name='AttentionLayer')
---> 32 attn_out, attn_states = attention([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])
     33 
     34 # Concat attention output and decoder LSTM output

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. I was doing something really stupid.